# Invalidate session when user log in again - cluster

Tags: java, caching, websphere, websphere-7, dynacache

My application is deployed on webshpere, in a cluster environment with two nodes.
The requirement is:
when user log in back, invalidate previous session.
I'm able to met the requirement when the second login is directed on the node where the previous session is on, otherwise if the second login happens on a different node I can't say if there are other active sessions.
I tryed using a cache resource on websphere (Dynacache) but session object is not serializable, so I'm not able to.
Which could be a good solution for this?

Comment: Sessions can be memory-to-memory replicated between nodes (in the network deployment version), or stored on a central database for all nodes to use.

Comment: Do you have an example for storing in a database?

Comment: In the web container, you can configure the session parameters.  One is a configuration for a session database.